# How can I read and play a video file from my table in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I used to directly control the video playback,But when i read from table it's not work

My sources :

```
<video id="vd_file" runat="server" controls="controls" 
       width="400px" height="300px" src="" />

string ss =ec.Getds("select product_other4 from products where Product_Id='6' " );

vd_file.InnerHtml = "<video src=\"" + ss + " \"   id=\"vd_file\"   runat=\"server\"   controls=\"controls\"   width=\"400px\"   height=\"300px\"    /> " ;
```

Comment: Why are you are setting the `InnerHtml` attribute? Surely you want to change the `src` attribute - `vd_file.Attributes["src"] = ss;`?

Comment: Also why retrieve all columns using `SELECT *` when you are only interested in one (product_other4) - [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: thanks , i used vd_file.Attributes["src"] = ss;  and it's ok